# Excel - Conditional value if all cells in range equal a specific string

Tags: excel

Apart from a nested IF statement, is there a more elegant way of accomplishing it?

The idea is that if the values in Columns A-D are "Green", the Overall column says "Green" but only if all four (Q1-Q4) are Green. If there's at least one Amber in one of the Qs, the Overall should be Amber.

I know I could do a long IF statement but was hoping there will be a shorter way. We're using O365 and the spreadsheet will end up on a share point.

EDIT: Apologies. I should have mentioned that there can be a couple of other values apart from Amber. So it's really between either All are Green or NOT all are Green.

Cells are:

[image]

Comment: You can do it in many way. `Sumif(), Countif(), Sumproduct()` all these functions you can try. See my answer below

Comment: Thank you and apologies. I should have mentioned it earlier. Apart from the "Amber" value, there can be a couple of others ("Red", "N/A", etc). It's really either they are all Green or NOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:D2,"Amber")>0,"Amber","Green")
```

[image]

This will also work

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(A2:D2="Amber")),"Amber","Green")
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used your logic and amended it to: =IF(COUNTIF(A6:D6,"Green")<4,"Amber","Green")